# Populate a column in R [using if statements?] based on variable in another column

Tags: r, if-statement, rename

A seemingly simple task that I am struggling with:

I collected behavior data and have a column ("Behavior") in which I recorded what behavior is taking place. I would like to group these behaviors into categories and fill in a column ("BehaviorGroup") with the category name.

An example of how this might look:

```
Behavior      BehaviorGroup
bite          aggressive contact
ram           aggressive contact
avoid         avoid
fast-approach aggressive approach
flee          avoid
fast-approach aggressive approach

etc.
```

So I would like to use the behaviors listed under the Behavior column (which I already have) to fill in the BehaviorGroup column (which is currently empty) based on the category.

For the example above:
"bite" and "ram" are "aggressive contact",
"avoid" and "flee" are "avoid", and
"fast-approach" is "aggressive approach"

I have MANY more but I'm hoping this is enough to get started on how to tackle the code to do this!
I would greatly appreciate any and all help with this!

Here's code for what I would be working with, based on the example given:

```
Behavior <- c("bite", "ram", "avoid", "fast-approach", "flee", "fast-approach")
BehaviorGroup <- c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")
data.frame(Behavior,BehaviorGroup)
```

I'm just trying to fill in the BehaviorGroup column.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  mutate(BehaviorGroup = case_when(Behavior %in% c("bite", "ram") ~ "aggressive contact",
                                   Behavior %in% c("avoid", "flee") ~ "flee",
                                   Behavior %in% c("fast-approach") ~ "aggressive approach"))

       Behavior       BehaviorGroup
1          bite  aggressive contact
2           ram  aggressive contact
3         avoid                flee
4 fast-approach aggressive approach
5          flee                flee
6 fast-approach aggressive approach
```

Or if you like `base` and `ifelse`

```
df$BehaviorGroup <-ifelse(df$Behavior %in% c("bite", "ram"), "aggressive contact", NA)
df$BehaviorGroup[is.na(df$BehaviorGroup) == TRUE] <-ifelse(df$Behavior[is.na(df$BehaviorGroup) == TRUE] %in% c("avoid", "flee"), "flee", NA)
df$BehaviorGroup[is.na(df$BehaviorGroup) == TRUE] <-ifelse(df$Behavior[is.na(df$BehaviorGroup) == TRUE] %in% c("fast-approach"), "aggressive approach", NA)

df
       Behavior       BehaviorGroup
1          bite  aggressive contact
2           ram  aggressive contact
3         avoid                flee
4 fast-approach aggressive approach
5          flee                flee
6 fast-approach aggressive approach
```

Comment: Great!!! I wasn't able to get tidyverse to install for some reason so I may have to troubleshoot that but the ifelse code worked and makes sense so I can apply it to the rest of my data. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

In base r:

```
d <- data.frame(Behavior,BehaviorGroup, stringsAsFactors = F)

d$BehaviorGroup[grepl("bite|ram", d$Behavior)] <- "agressive"

       Behavior BehaviorGroup
1          bite     agressive
2           ram     agressive
3         avoid            NA
4 fast-approach            NA
5          flee            NA
6 fast-approach            NA
```

If instead you want exact matches:

```
d$BehaviorGroup[grepl("^bite$|^ram$", d$Behavior)] <- "agressive"
```